# Injecting service to controller fails in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My code is like this

```
Controller.js
var errorMessage = { MessageHeader: "Error", Message: "Something went wrong. Please try again later." };
    angular.module('RateRequestApp.controllers', []).controller('ReadOnlyController', [
    '$scope',  'updateTruckNoService', 'messageModalService', '$modal',
    function ($scope,  updateTruckNoService, messageModalService, $modal) {

        messageModalService.showMessageModal(errorMessage);
    }
]);
Services.js
angular.module('RateRequestApp.services').factory('messageModalService', [ '$modal', messageModalService]);
function messageModalService($modal) {
    function showMessageModal(response) {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'MessageModal.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
            resolve: {
                items: function () {
                    return response;
                }
            }
        });
    };
}

App.JS
angular.module('RateRequestApp', [
   'RateRequestApp.services',
   'RateRequestApp.controllers',
   'ui.bootstrap',
   'angular-loading-bar'
]);
```

Everything looks okay to me, But this throws an error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'showMessageModal' of undefined

at line

```
  messageModalService.showMessageModal(errorMessage);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `showMessageModal` function is just defined in your `messageModalService` function. You're not returning it, so nobody can access it.

In fact, you're not returning anything, so your factory is producing `undefined` when it is invoked.

```
function messageModalService($modal) {
    function showMessageModal(response) {
        // ...
    }

    return {showMessageModal: showMessageModal};
}
```

or you can also just do:

```
function messageModalService($modal) {
    return {
        showMessageModal: function (response) {
            // ...
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is simple that your service "messageModalService" is not returning the method 'showMessageModal', try to return form the methd messageModalService like below sample, it should work :)

```
return{
    showMessageModal: showMessageModal
};
```